# R. Display only TRUE values from a boolean expression?

Tags: r, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

Data science student here. New to R, in my first course. I've spent way too much time trying to figure out this exercise, so I figured I would ask someone on here.

I have created a dataframe built from 4 matrices, titled bee_numbers_data_2:

```
buff_tail garden_bee red_tail honeybee carder_bee
    10          8       18       12          8
     1          3        9       13         27
    37         19        1       16          6
     5          6        2        9         32
    12          4        4       10         23
```

The exercise asks us to only show honeybee numbers >= 10.

So I've created a boolean expression to display the TRUE FALSE statements:

```
bee_numbers_data_2$honeybee>=10
```

Which returns:

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

However, I want to display a list of the VALUES of the true statements, not a list of TRUE FALSE statements.

I've been pouring over my textbook and the internet trying to figure out this simple problem, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: have a look at `?which`

Comment: Look at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/ and https://r4ds.had.co.nz/

Comment: Read up on R subsetting. In particular, `?"["`.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a fairly simple question, covered in most introductory texts on R, I could not find a duplicate on SO, so it seems worth answering here.

Let's break it down.  As you already showed, we can use boolean expressions to generate a vector of boolean values:

```
bee_numbers_data_2 = data.frame(honeybee=c(12,13,16,9,10)) 
bee_numbers_data_2$honeybee >= 10
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

If we want to know which of those are true, we can use the base R function `which`:

```
which(bee_numbers_data_2$honeybee >= 10)
# [1] 1 2 3 5
```

If we want to know the original values corresponding to those position indices, we can use those indices to subset the original data, using `[`

```
bee_numbers_data_2$honeybee[which(bee_numbers_data_2$honeybee >= 10)]
# [1] 12 13 16 10
```

Or, equivalently and a little more simple, we can subset using the boolean vales directly:

```
bee_numbers_data_2$honeybee[bee_numbers_data_2$honeybee >= 10]
```

Note that as you learn more R, you will find that there are also some more advanced ways to filter and subset data, such as the packages `data.table` and `dplyr`.  However, it is best to understand how to use base R first, as shown above.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it was a simple function that I was just missing. Another question. If I wanted to subset the data from 2 columns using a boolean value, how would I accomplish that? Say I want to know which data from the honeybee and buff tail columns were >= 10. I tried to just separate the two commands with a comma inside of the 'which' function, but that didn't work..

Comment: This is not the right place for an extended tutorial on the basics of R.  I suggest that you work through one of the many courses and texts available.